# Can't target two specific properties in a DOM element

Tags: javascript

I have a image element nested in a div:

```
            <div id="Container" class="container">
                <div id="1" title="belief" class="list mix category-1" data-myorder="1"><img class="crest" data-myorder="1" src="public/images/belief.svg" alt="belief"></div>

                <div id="2" title="integrity" class="list mix category-1" data-myorder="2"><img class="crest" src="public/images/integrity.svg" alt="integrity"></div>

                <div id="3" title="respect" class="list mix category-1" data-myorder="3"><img class="crest" src="public/images/respect.svg" alt="respect"></div>

                <div id="4" title="trust" class="list mix category-2" data-myorder="4"><img class="crest" src="public/images/trust.svg" alt="trust"></div>

                <div id="5" title="humility" class="list mix category-1" data-myorder="5"><img class="crest" src="public/images/humility.svg" alt="humility"></div>

            </div>
```

When I try to target the `id` like below the 'hit' area doesn't include the image nested inside*. (I am using [mixitup](http://codepen.io/patrickkunka/pen/ugiwx) like this iteration linked here and have placed the image in the div, floating left in the list view and the image takes up the whole div in the box view).

```
function templateLoader(e) {
    var doc = document,
        event = EventUtility.getEvent(e),
        target = EventUtility.getTarget(event);

    console.dir(event.currentTarget.children);

    if (event.target !== event.currentTarget) {

        switch (event.target.dataset.myorder) {

            case '1':
                $.Mustache.options.warnOnMissingTemplates = true;

                $.Mustache.load('./public/js/templates/templates.html')
                    .fail(function() {
                        $('body').append('Failed to load templates from <code>templates.html</code>');
                    })
                    .done(function() {

                        $('body').append($.Mustache.render('belief', {
                            coreIdeas: 'Belief'
                        }));

                        $('#appButton').on('click', function(event) {
                            $('#overlay').remove();
                        });
                    });
                break;

            case '2':
                $.Mustache.options.warnOnMissingTemplates = true;
                $.Mustache.load('./public/js/templates/templates.html')
                    .fail(function() {
                        $('body').append('Failed to load templates from <code>templates.html</code>');
                    })
                    .done(function() {
                        $('body').append($.Mustache.render('integrity', {
                            coreIdeas: 'Integrity'
                        }));

                        $('#appButton').on('click', function(event) {
                            $('#overlay').remove();
                        });

                    });
                break;

            case '3':

                $.Mustache.options.warnOnMissingTemplates = true;
                $.Mustache.load('./public/js/templates/templates.html')
                    .fail(function() {
                        $('body').append('Failed to load templates from <code>templates.html</code>');
                    })
                    .done(function() {
                        $('body').append($.Mustache.render('respect', {
                            coreIdeas: 'Respect'
                        }));

                        $('#appButton').on('click', function(event) {
                            $('#overlay').remove();
                        });
                    });


                break;

            case '4':
                $.Mustache.options.warnOnMissingTemplates = true;
                $.Mustache.load('./public/js/templates/templates.html')
                    .fail(function() {
                        $('body').append('Failed to load templates from <code>templates.html</code>');
                    })
                    .done(function() {
                        $('body').append($.Mustache.render('trust', {
                            coreIdeas: 'Trust'
                        }));


                        $('#appButton').on('click', function(event) {
                            $('#overlay').remove();
                        });
                    });

                break;
            case '5':
                $.Mustache.options.warnOnMissingTemplates = true;
                $.Mustache.load('./public/js/templates/templates.html')
                    .fail(function() {
                        $('body').append('Failed to load templates from <code>templates.html</code>');
                    })
                    .done(function() {
                        $('body').append($.Mustache.render('humility', {
                            coreIdeas: 'Humility'
                        }));

                        $('#appButton').on('click', function(event) {
                            $('#overlay').remove();
                        });
                    });

                break;




        }
    }
}
```

One solution I had was duplicating the `my-order=1` attribute on the image element; and then select like so:

```
switch(event.target.dataset.myorder)
```

but I wanted to remain DRY!

Thanks all!

Comment: Which element is the listener on? If the listener is on the DIV, `target` will be the image, `currentTarget` will be the DIV.

Comment: And the image doesn't have an ID or `data-myorder` attribute.

Comment: Side note: Although in HTML5, the restrictions on allowed characters for ids are very loose, I normally stick to the HTML4 spec on ids to prevent some problems.

Comment: Hey all, I updated my code. The listener is on a `Container` div so I can take advantage of `event-propagation`

Comment: You are talking about dry code and are seriously duplicating the same code over and over again just to change a parameter name??

Comment: @Barmar - I actually tried adding the same `attribute` on the image which worked, but didn't know if you could do that, like resusing a `id`, you know?

Comment: @Christoph -  hear ya, I am still learning, and actually proposed this code in a slightly different way, to fix that part about it, but didn't get any feedback, Actually I got shipped off to a sister site of SOF, but didn't get much help there...

Comment: I don't know, what your `EventUtility` object is doing, but you should: 1) check what element is returned as `target` and which as `currentTarget`. Depending on that, you have to select the correct element. 2) you can completely omit the `switch` and just hand over the `render` parameter which is dynamically retrieved, e.g. from the alt attribute (or a data attribute if you must).

Comment: @Christoph - Actually I was doing a `console.dir(event.currentTarget.children);` and digging into the elements and seeing if I could use something combined with a `||` operator, something like — `switch (event.target.dataset.myorder || crest.image)` of course the stuff after the `||` operator is pseudo-code. ;) How would you completely omit the switch and just get the render parameter from the alt attribute?